# What does 多少 mean in 但是我也相对得到多少的感动?

Tags: grammar, meaning

This sentence is from oral Chinese, but I want to understand what 多少 means.

> 但是我也相对得到多少的感动。

Is 多少 an adverb here?
Also, is 感动 a noun?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noKbiu-4YiU

1:23

Comment: https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/17492281

Comment: https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/17100040

Comment: This is a bad sentence. I don't see the point of analyzing bad sentences.

Comment: This is a site for learners of the language, hopefully seeking help. If every sentence that is put here has to be "good", (otherwise it should ignored or closed), then where is the learning process? Perhaps one could point out why it is a "bad sentence" so that the OP learn something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "但是我也相对[得到]多少的[感动]。", "得到" is a verb for 'obtain' therefore, "感动" must be a noun for "sensation", and [多少的] would be an adjective for "some"

The problem is, "多少" is short for "多多少少"(somewhat) or "或多或少" (more or less) and it is an adverb, The author tried to add 的 to an adverb to make it an adjective.

From the context, we see the writer wanted to say "某程度上的" (some degree of), which is an adjective, but instead, he added (的) to "多少" to make it an adjective", functions as "some" (一些)

A simpler sentence would be "但是我也相对得到某程度上的感动。" or "但是我也相对得到一些感动。"

Comment: Thanks, this is a really helpful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

What 多少 means?

In this context it means "somewhat"

"Somewhat" is an adverb.

多少的感动 = "somewhat affected / moved / touched"

Answer (score 0):

> 但是我也相对得到多少的感动。

The sentence doesn't sound right to me.  I'd take it as a misuse of 多少.  多少 is used in a question or a exclamatory sentence.  e. g.  你有多少钱？ 那得是多少钱啊！

Comment: Yes, it's a "bad" sentence, (grammatically & semantically), but we just have to take it as we find it. Making it a "better" sentence would not serve the purpose. We just confine ourselves to answering the OP's specific question.

Comment: @WayneCheah If it's ungrammatical, it doesn't make any sense to explain the grammar point.  The sentence is plain wrong to me.  Maybe, it's regional?

Comment: What I meant was explain only the specific part of the sentence which the OP's question touches on and not the whole or the rest of the sentence. That was why I just confined my answer to 多少 as OP's specific question was (a) "what 多少 means", and (b) "Is 多少 an adverb here?" It's like a mechanic being asked to fix a car door only, not to repaint the car to another color.

Comment: It would be different if the question was to comment on or to rewrite the whole sentence, which you could still do, (if you are so inclined), not as an answer but as an ancillary comment.

Comment: @WayneCheah The OP's question is about the meaning and part of speech in the sentence(which is ungrammatical). If he/she is asking the word 多少 out of that sentence, the dictionary should be able to serve him/her well. How would you answer what the part of speech the word "often" is in the sentence "she's an often student" in English? Is it an adverb or adjective?

Comment: Which is why besides answering  多少 , I also answer the part semantically relevant to it, namely, 感动. It is therefore possible to isolate 多少的感动 from the rest of the sentence, which I did by saying "多少的感动 = "somewhat affected / moved / touched", which by itself is grammatically and semantically acceptable, unlike "she's an often student" which is patently not.

Comment: @WayneCheah Unfortunately, the issue I take from the sentence is the exact phrase "多少的感动"，which is wrong. Otherwise, the sentence is ok over all.

Comment: Which is precisely why I did not say "多少的感动" is correct or good language structure, but "acceptable". You, a native speaker, of course could say it better or correctly, but that's another story.

Comment: @WayneCheah Not sure what you meant by 'acceptable'. 多少的感动 is very vague.  If someone actually says it, I don't know how much 感动 he/she feels, few, much? We can't tell at all.

Comment: Quote:- " I don't know how much 感动 he/she feels, few, much?"  That's why I translated 多少 as "somewhat" which is defined as "to a moderate extent or by a moderate amount" 感动 of course cannot be mathetically measured.